# Not understanding with "end of line" character

Tags: oracle, character, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT 'aaa
bbb' AS val FROM DUAL
)
SELECT val from t
```

Result from this query is:

```
VAL    
-----
aaabbb
```

what is quite clear for me.

But this:

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT 'aaa
bbb' AS val FROM DUAL
)
SELECT val, replace(val, 'a', '-') AS replace from t;
```

returns:

```
VAL    |REPLACE
---------------------
aaa bbb| ---bbb
```

Question: In second example, from where appeared space between `aaa` and `bbb` in column VAL?

P.S. I test this in SQLDeveloper (version 4.0.2.15)

**UPDATE**

Not only `replace` causes that bug, this query also:

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT 'aaa
bbb' AS val FROM DUAL
)
SELECT val   ---------
from t;
```

Result is: `aaa bbb`

If remove comment dashs, result is without space.

Comment: Very interesting and strange, might be a bug. Reproduced in Oracle 11.2.0.2.0. What version are you on?

Comment: I have `12.1.0.1.0` version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it might be a bug. I reproduced it in 11.2.0.2.0. The call to `replace` seems to trigger some kind of side effect to the value of `val` where a space character is being inserted:

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT 'aaa
bbb' AS val FROM DUAL
)
SELECT val, dump(val) from t;

"aaabbb"    Typ=96 Len=7: 97,97,97,10,98,98,98

WITH t AS (
SELECT 'aaa
bbb' AS val FROM DUAL
)
SELECT val, replace(val, 'a', '-'), dump(val) AS replace from t;

"aaa bbb"   "--- bbb"   Typ=96 Len=8: 97,97,97,32,10,98,98,98
```

Notice that the linefeed character is in the original value of `val`. In the query that calls `replace`, there may be a bug that is causing the value of `val` to be converted in some way that causes the space to be inserted.

EDIT: as per jonearles' comment, this appears to be a bug in SQL Developer 4.0. The problem doesn't occur when I run these in another tool (e.g. Apex).

Comment: Yes there is something wrong, and not only `replace` causes this strange situation, for example this query also inserts space: please see update in question

Comment: It seems like some kind of transformation that is (or isn't) done when the main query does more than just query the base `val`. I wonder if it happens if `val` is a bind variable instead of a literal string?

Comment: This looks like a bug in SQL Developer 4.0.  Everything works fine in SQL Developer 3.2.20.09 on Oracle 12c, but it breaks on SQL Developer 4.0.2.15 on Oracle 12c.

Comment: Thanks jonearles, confirmed. Updated.